# wp nav menu: show submenu below li item

Tags: php, menus, css

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to show the submenu's outside of the relevant `li` tag.
For example, this php:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu'  =>  'side',
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class'      => 'side-menu'
));
?>
```

will render the menu like so:

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-01" class="menu-item">Menu 01</li>
    <li id="menu-item-02" class="menu-item">Menu 02
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">Sub 01</li>
            <li class="submenu-item">Sub 02</li>
            <li class="submenu-item">Sub 03</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-03" class="menu-item">Menu 03</li>
    <li id="menu-item-04" class="menu-item">Menu 04</li>
</ul>
```

...when what I'd actually like to achieve is something like this:

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-01" class="menu-item">Menu 01</li>
    <li id="menu-item-02" class="menu-item">Menu 02</li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">Sub 01</li>
            <li class="submenu-item">Sub 02</li>
            <li class="submenu-item">Sub 03</li>
        </ul>
    <li id="menu-item-03" class="menu-item">Menu 03</li>
    <li id="menu-item-04" class="menu-item">Menu 04</li>
</ul>
```

with the relevant submenu sitting below it's corresponding menu item, the reason being the submenus are initially hidden and slide down upon clicking the relevant menu item and each menu item is styled, thus wrapping a submenu inside it throws everything out. Is this at all possible?

Comment: You don't need to alter the markup to be invalid in order to make this work. CSS and Javascript work perfectly well with the valid markup, but pure CSS/Javascript questions are off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the output of the menu, by creating a new menu [Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function). I wouldn't recommend this solution, however, since you're attempting to do something that's actually invalid HTML - the `ul` tag should *only* have `li` tags inside it, *never* anything else.

I know it's possible to create the solution you're looking for with css and javascript, as I've done it many times before. I can't speak to your particular situation for an exact solution, but possibly try styling the `a` links inside the `li` for the main menu; then your nested submenus can have whatever styles they need.